# Is there a way to access an input parameter indirectly?

Tags: r, function

Currently i have a large function with a lot of parameters (each one has a default value) and i want to test the sensitivity of each parameter. Therefore I wondered if there is a way to address inputs of a function via the respective string.

```
b <- function(x = 2,y = 3){
  return(x+y)
}

param = 'y'
assign(param, 2)
param_name = as.name(param)
b(param_name = get(param))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, because param_name is no input of the function b().

Thanks.

Comment: `assign(param, 2)` will erase first `param = 'y'`.. What actually want to do is not clear

Answer (score 2):

We could construct the call with `do.call` and use `setNames` inside:

```r
b <- function(x = 2, y = 3){
  return(x+y)
}

param <- 2
param_name <- "y"

do.call("b", setNames(list(param), param_name))
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pmap()` or its variant from `{purrr}` package. `expand.grid()` creates a dataframe containing all combinations of the possible parameters. If there are only two parameters, use `map2()`.

```
b <- function(x = 2, y = 3, z = 1){
  return(x+y+z)
}

p1 <- 1:2
p2 <- 3:4
p3 <- 5:6
params <- expand.grid(x = p1, y = p2, z = p3)

pmap(params, b)
```